# Randomized Relaxation of Complex Linear Assignment Problem

Tags: algorithm, linear-programming, polynomial-approximations, randomized-algorithm, assignment-problem

I am currently working on creating an algorithm to solve a complex assignment problem. The problem is basically as follows: there are `d` "sessions" each with `m` "sections" each with some maximum capacity; there are `n` people that will each give `r` preferences for each session. The objective is to assign optimally the people to one section *per session*.

The algorithm that I am thinking about is a linear program as follows.

> First, let Pⱼ∈[r]ᵈˣᵐ be the matrix of preferences for the j-th
> person (so it each element is ranked 0-r for each section in each
> session). Then we have M∈[n]ᵈˣᵐ as the matrix of section capacities. Then, we
> will define the variables Aⱼ∈{(0,1)}ᵈˣᵐ as the (unnormalized) assignment
> probabilities of the j-th person for each section in each session.
>
> We will maximize:
>
> ∑ⱼ〈Aⱼ,Pⱼ〉
>
> Subject to
>
> 0 < A_{jkl} < 1  ∀ (i,j,k)
>
> ∑ⱼ Aⱼᵢₖ≤Mᵢₖ  ∀ (i,k)
>
> The last step is to give final assignments for each person in each
> section using Aⱼₖ/∑ᵢAⱼₖᵢ as a categorical probability distribution for the j-th person in the k-th session.

Does this approach seem like it will give an approximately correct answer? If so, how would I go about finding the approximation ratio? If not, any tips on better approaches would be much appreciated. This is definitely a very difficult program to set up, so I apologize if my explanation was a bit hard to follow. I am happy to clarify anything.

Comment: Why are you dealing with "assignment probabilities" (which I don't think you could actually calculate because they are in no way independent).  Why not just formulate this as an assignment problem as a MIP?  There are many examples.  Including here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76475352/linear-programming-solver-ignore-constraints/76476093#76476093

Comment: I was originally thinking of doing a relaxation of an integer linear program with a final step of just taking the argmax(A_jk) as the section assignment, but then I thought that adding some stochasticity might give a more balanced structure and make the section capacity constrain work a bit better. I was trying to avoid doing a MIP since it is NP-hard, but I suppose for small values this is perhaps manageable.

Comment: If you want to make solutions more equitable, it is better to add this explicitly to the model.